# How I create a nested query with Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 6.
I have a form to create a meeting. I want to create a custom validator to check if the room is already occupied at that time. The query parameters are "room", "date_meeting", "start" and "end".

In other words, I want to make the following MySQL query with Laravel:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `meetings` 
WHERE id_room = 1 AND date = '2021-03-02' AND ((start_hour >= '22:00:00' AND start_hour < '23:00:00') OR (start_hour < '22:00:00' AND end_hour >= '23:00:00') OR (end_hour > '22:00:00' AND end_hour <= '23:00:00'))
```

I created the following query with Laravel but it doesn't work correctly:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $meetings = DB::table('meetings')
    ->where('id_room', request('room'))
    ->where('date', request('date_meeting'))
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('start_hour', '>=', request('start'))
        ->where('start_hour', '<', request('end'));
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('start_hour', '<', request('start'))
        ->where('end_hour', '>=', request('end'));
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('end_hour', '>', request('start'))
        ->where('end_hour', '<=', request('end'));
    })
    ->get();

    if(count($meetings) > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The room and the date work correctly in Laravel... but the time doesn't work well.
Have you some idea why it doesn't work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `orWhere` query is At the same level with `where('id_room', request('room'))`

You need to add two level nested query, something like this:

```php
$meetings = DB::table('meetings')
    ->where('id_room', request('room'))
    ->where('date', request('date_meeting'))
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function($sub_q) {
                  $sub_q->where('start_hour', '>=', request('start'))
                        ->where('start_hour', '<', request('end'));
              })
              ->orWhere(function($sub_q) {
                  $sub_q->where('start_hour', '<', request('start'))
                        ->where('end_hour', '>=', request('end'));
              })
              ->orWhere(function($sub_q) {
                   $sub_q->where('end_hour', '>', request('start'))
                         ->where('end_hour', '<=', request('end'));
              });
    })->get();
```